# How to install mobx 3

Tags: mobx

I was trying to install mobx 3 according to the instructions [here](https://mobx.js.org/).

I got mobx 2.7 after running this:

```
npm install mobx --save
```

Isn't mobx 3.x out?

Answer (score 3):

`npm install mobx@3.0.0 --save` to install exact version (e.g. 3.0.0)

`npm install mobx@^3.0.0 --save` to install latest 3.x version (you don't know exact number and want to include the latest fixes)

Answer (score 1):

`3.1.0` is the latest version. I would suspect you have `mobx@2.7.0` in your `package.json` as a `dependency` or `devDependency`.

Uninstall it and install it again:

```
npm uninstall -S mobx
npm uninstall -D mobx
npm install -S mobx
```